# android progressDialog is static

Tags: android, static, progressdialog

I have an issue with my ProgressDialog object. When I show it first time, it is spinning, but after I dismiss it and show it again, the dialog is static, it it not spinning... Can you please tell me why? All of this happens in the UI thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you doing any processing in the UI thread during the second show of the `ProgressDialog`? If so, you need to move the processing to a background thread. Otherwise, the progress dialog does not get the CPU to update(spin) itself.